# Scroll Modal JSP

Tags: java, html, html5, jsp

Estoy creando un modal en un jsp (html) pero tengo problemas con el scroll, ya que al querer bajar, baja la página de atras, he buscado varias opciones, pero ninguna con resultado...
les comparto parte de las clases de dicho modal

```
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="modal_listar_documentos" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width:75%; height:75%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close btnModalGFijosCerrar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPersonaPostulante" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Documentos</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="get" action="?parametro=sesion">
                                <input type="hidden" name="rut" id="rut" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="dv"  id="dv"/>
                                </form>
            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>      
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="ibox-content forum-container">
                    <div id="listado_documentos_postulante">
                        <table class="table display responsive" id="tabla_documentos_postulante">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Rut</th>
                                    <th>Nombre del Archivo</th>
                                    <th>Descargar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbody_tabla_documentos_postulante"></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnCerrarModalAgregarPDF" type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPersonaPostulante" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="assets/js/functions_ctrl/mantenedor_Postulantes.js"></script>  
<script src="assets/js/functions_ctrl/documento_Postulantes_Persona.js"></script>
```

Comment: $('#modal-form').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#modal-form').css('overflow', 'auto');
  }
 );
Encontre ese codigo pero es de Js, funciona... pero genera un doble scroll

Comment: En lugar de agregarle el auto al overflow ponle hidden, con eso deshabilitas un scroll

Comment: @TheVicShow no sirve si cambio el auto por el hidden

Comment: Podrías agregar el modal completo para poder replicarlo? y ver si se logra una solución

Comment: @TheVicShow Listo

Comment: Replique tu html pero si abre el modal normal, si lo que necesitas es bloquear el body para que quite el scroll en lugar de $('#modal-form').css('overflow', 'auto'); usa $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); el problema es que cuando cierres el modal tienes que regresar el overflow a auto porque no aparecerá el scroll principal